# Не работает регулярное выражение по заданному шаблону в pattern input html

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, шаблоны-проектирования

Не фильтруются числа по заданному шаблону в pattern (выводятся также трехзначные числа). Хочу вывести только четырехзначные числа. На regex101.com регулярное выражение работает.
P.S.: пробовал также рег. выражение "[0-9]{4}", все равно не работает

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="POST">
<input type="number" name="numbers" pattern="^([0-9]{4})?$">
<button type="submit" id="myBtn">Send data</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
input:invalid {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
</style>

<form action="POST">

<input type="text" name="numbers" required="required" pattern="\d{4}">

<button type="submit" id="myBtn">Send data</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ещё можно запретить ввод букв:

```
<input type="text" name="numbers" required="required" pattern="\d{4}"
    oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');">
```

Comment: в моем случае, у меня другая форма (код был приведен для примера) и action=POST. Но pattern="[0-9]{4}" я уже вставлял и он не работает.

Comment: Я поправил чуток :)

Comment: ввел pattern="\d\d\d\d", тоже не работает

Comment: type=text required="required"